# Is it possible to install bitnami/etcd using my own PVC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I am using AWS and I created EFS for my new PV and PVC.
I have K8s cluster with nodes in different zones, so I decided to use EFS for cases when node will be killed or died and recreated on node in different zone.

I also created PV with name:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: some-test-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: "gp3"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-[ID which I got from AWS console]
```

As a next step - I am trying to install bitnami/etcd (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/etcd) but I cant configure it to use my PV (I am using values.yaml - `helm install etcd -f values.yaml --namespace test bitnami/etcd`):

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
  storageClass: ""
  annotations: {}

  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  size: 1Gi
  ## @param persistence.selector [object] Selector to match an existing Persistent Volume
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#selector
  ##
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
      - { key: name, operator: In, values: [some-test-pv] }
```

But looks like it trying to create PVC using `ebs.csi.aws.com`.
Is it possible to point it to EFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In values you can use this:

```
persistence:
...
  existingClaim: some-test-pv
```